# Upgrading ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04, no upgrade notice!

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

How come I don't get any upgrade notice on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS for an upgrade to 18.04?
Shouldn't I normally receive an upgrade notice on my system?
On the ubuntu wiki it says: Upgrades from 16.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after 18.04.1's release expected in early August.
It's been more than two weeks since the release of 18.04.1!
Should I wait for a upgrade notification or I can proceed and upgrade?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wait. They try to fix some issue leading to a bad upgrade experience and try to make the update available during the next week(s).  [source](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-August/004556.html)

Answer (score 7):

The upgrade notification for 16.04 has been delayed due to a bug in the upgrading process, see [this mail on the ubuntu-release mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2018-August/004556.html).

A fix for this problem is currently tested and if everything's going well you should get a upgrade notification next week.